# Facebook Graph - getting the Facebook ID - using PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a form in which I post a Facebook URL.

I process the URL in a PHP script to get the Facebook ID.

Form:

```
<form name="input" method="post"  action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">

<input name="url" required>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

PHP Script

```
$url =  $_REQUEST["url"];



$jsonurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$url.'.json';
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);


$fbid = ($json_output->id);

echo $fbid;
```

I've not been able to pull in the ID. I'm echoing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL would be:

```
$jsonurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$url;
```

...while $url must be a Graph API Endpoint or Vanity URL that is available in public, without Access Token. No ".json" required.

For example:

```
$url = 'bladauhu';
$json_result = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$url);
$json = json_decode($json_result);
echo $json->id;
```

Comment: sorry, i just forgot file_get_contents, my bad :)

Comment: I managed to make it work using $jsonurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$url; - New Code: http://pastebin.com/5pL3WQZn

Comment: actually, i made another mistake, i just tested it. it´s of course json_decode - but you don´t need to decode AND encode it in a row. i will update my answer so it´s correct.